# jqgrid different editrules for when adding and editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which is used for editing users (permissions, name etc.).
I also have a Password field, which, in editing mode, is write-only.
Meaning- the password is not displayed, but if a user inserts a value for this field- then the password is changed.
My issue is that when editing an existing user, I obviously want the password field to be optional. But when adding a new user, I want to make this field required.
How can this be acheived?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your problem you can use different validation methods when editing and adding.

example:

`function validate_add(posdata, obj)
{
   if(posdata.PASSWORD==null || posdata.PASSWORD=="" || posdata.PASSWORD==undefined)
    return [false, "Please enter the pasword"];`

return [true, ""];
}

function validate_edit(posdata, obj)
{
   //you can ignore this because you dont want to verify password
}

// in jqgrid

grid.navGrid('#pager',{add:true,addtext:'Add',edit:true,edittext:'Edit',del:true,deltext:'Del', search:true,searchtext:'Find',refresh:true}, //options
{width:700,reloadAfterSubmit:true, beforeSubmit:validate_edit}, // edit options
{width:700,reloadAfterSubmit:true, beforeSubmit:validate_add}, // add options
{}, //del options
{} //search options
);

Comment: You are right, the `beforeSubmit` can be used for custom validation. So +1 from me. After your answer will be accepted I'll post description of another way: how one can use *standard validation* with `editrules`, but **two different** `editrules` values for Add and Edit dialogs.

Comment: im afraid that you cannot do it with <code>editrules</code> because editrules is under <code>common_rules</code> module which is common for both add and edit... it will b great if you can do it...

Comment: @Sandeep: There are no way **to define** different `editrules`, but one can **change** the value of the `editrules` objects inside of `beforeCheckValues` method for example or inside of some other [form edit events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) called before validation checking.

Comment: hmmm actually im confused... can you please post that alternative as an answer... thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I use method "setColProp" for this

```
......
{ //Edit dialog options
beforeCheckValues: function(postdata, formid, mode) {
  grid.setColProp('Password', {editrules: {required: false}}); 
},
{ //Add dialog options
beforeCheckValues: function(postdata, formid, mode) {
  grid.setColProp('Password', {editrules: {required: true}}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sandeep posted correct code because `beforeSubmit` can be used for the custom validation.

There are alternative approach to do what you want. One can't **define** different [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules), but one can change the value of the `editrules` objects inside of beforeCheckValues method for example or inside of some other [form edit events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) called *before* validation check.

Here is the schema of the code which can change the `editrules`:

```
var grid = $("#list"),
    getColumnIndexByName = function(columnName) {
        var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel'), // grid[0].p.colModel
            i=0, l=cm.length;
        for (; i<l; i++) {
            if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
                return i; // return the index
            }
        }
        return -1;
    },
    addEditrulesPassword={required:true /*some other settings can follow*/},
    editEditrulesPassword={required:false /*some other settings can follow*/};

// ... first of all we define the grid 
grid.jqGrid({
    // all parameters including the definition of the column
    // with the name 'Password' inside of `colModel`
});

grid.jqGrid(
    'navGrid','#pager',{/*navGrid options*/},
    {//Edit dialog options
    },
    {//Add dialog options
        beforeCheckValues:function(postdata,$form,oper) {
            // get reference to the item of colModel which correspond
            // to the column 'Password' which we want to change
            var cm = grid[0].p.colModel[getColumnIndexByName('Password')];
            cm.editrules = addEditrulesPassword;
        },
        onclickSubmit:function(ge,postdata) {
            // get reference to the item of colModel which correspond
            // to the column 'Password' which we want to change
            var cm = grid[0].p.colModel[getColumnIndexByName('Password')];
            cm.editrules = editEditrulesPassword;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit dirty solution for inline edit:

```
function inlineCustomValidation(value, colname) {

        var savedRow = jQuery("#grid").getGridParam("savedRow");

        if (savedRow[0].some_required_field == "")

            //add operation validation

        } else {

           //edit operation validation

        }
    };
```

[**savedRow**](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)   array.  This is a readonly property and is used in inline and cell editing modules to store the data, before editing the row or cell. See Cell Editing and Inline Editing.

Answer (score 0):

The below script is to validate jqgrid inline edit cell, it won't allow user to enter any special characters except dot(.) used to specify decimal separator

```
{ name: 'Amount', width: 22, label: 'Cost', editable: true, align: "right", sorttype: 'int', search: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: "$", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00' },
            editoptions: {
                dataInit: function(element) {
                    $(element).keypress(function (e) {
                        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 46 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57 )) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```