# how to implement jqgrid inline editing and custom validation?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid, an I am trying to implement the following scenarios but I am unable to get it the correct way.

This is my scenarios:

1. I have three rows like personal email, mobile number, and twitter url. It needs to have another column Data type, possibly values such as email, phone and url.
2. Now each of the rows I will enter the value for need to perform some
   validation like email format, or phone format.
3. When I press the Add button, it needs to create a new row and ask me the info for
   each column, like Name of column and Data type.
4. When I enter the value of each row, it needs to validate based on
   Data type column.
5. If I press the Edit button, the entire grid need to be editable and
   needs to perform validation on each cell after edit event triggers.

My code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //debugger;
        var val;
        var lastsel2;
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            width: 770,
            colNames: ['Mechanism', 'Data Type', 'Value', 'Active Flag', 'Created'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'Mechanism', index: 'Mechanism', width: 175, editable: true },
            { name: 'DataType', index: 'Datatype', width: 175, editable: true },
        { name: 'Value', index: 'Value', width: 105, editable: true, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validate} },
        {name: 'ActiveFlag', width: 112, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox" },
        { name: 'Created', index: 'Created', width: 124}]
        });
$('#save').live('click', function () {
            var ids = $("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var val = $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'Value');
                var dataType = $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'DataType');
                $('#colValue').html(val + dataType);
                var va = $('#colValue').find('input[name=value]').val();
                var daT = $('#colValue').find('input[name=Datatype]').attr('value');

                switch (daT) {
                    case "Phone":
                        if (!$.jgrid.isEmpty(va)) {

                        }
                        else
                            alert("Phone Number Field is required");
                        break;
                    case "Email":
                        if (!$.jgrid.isEmpty(va)) {

                        }
                        else
                            alert("Email Field is required");
                        break;
                    case "URL":
                        if (!$.jgrid.isEmpty(va)) {
                        }
                        else
                            alert("URL Field is required")
                        break;
                    case "":
                        alert("Fields are not null")
                }
            }
        });

        $('input[value=Edit]').click(function () {
            var ids = $('#list').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                //$('#list').jqGrid('editRow', ids[i]);
                jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
            }
        });
        var data = [{ Mechanism: "Mobile Phone", DataType: "Phone" }, { Mechanism: "Personal Email", DataType: "Email" }, { Mechanism: "Facebook URL", DataType: "URL"}];
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, data[i]);
        val = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question this really all boils down to validation, the add an edit functionality of can be added and then custom validation called.

Ex:

```
jQuery("#list").navGrid('#pager', {
    add: true,
    addtext: 'Add',
    edit: true,
    edittext: 'Edit',
    del: true,
    deltext: 'Del',
    search: true,
    searchtext: 'Find',
    refresh: true
}, //options
{
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    beforeSubmit: validate_edit
}, // edit options
{
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    beforeSubmit: validate_add
}, // add options
{}, //del options
{} //search options
);
```

Validation (could be different or the same based on your needs)

```
function validate_add(posdata, obj) {//validation code}

function validate_edit(posdata, obj) {//validation code}
```

Ref:
[jqgrid different editrules for when adding and editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095069/jqgrid-different-editrules-for-when-adding-and-editing)

In the end it would really clean up a bunch of the code you wrote trying to interact with the grid for validation.

Comment: But i have a button control for add,edit and also if i click edit button, the entire grid need to be editable. Then if i update value an each row, i need to perform validation based on DataType column. If you not understand please let me know.

Comment: You can call on the same function as part of your button handler to verify the data you are about to submit to the server. Editing the whole grid at once? I'm not sure if that is possible and sorry I didn't get that from your question.

Comment: Plus would you be just editing the displayed data currently in the grid, or editing the entire data set that the grid displays...I"m curious what is your requirement that is pushing a whole grid edit at once?

Comment: Ok Mark, the main requirement is, i need to perform cell validation based on previous cell value in the same Row, whether it is a Row editing or Cell editing or whole grid editing at once. Consider one of my row column  value **Email**, so i enter the value in another column(cell) in same row means, i need to validate **Email formatting**..Now you understand? please let me know..Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: I think that a process where you edit rows once at a time (I don't think editing a whole grid at once is even possible, but I'm not 100% sure) would be the best way to go.  As above as part of editing a row, you can perform validation on any of the cell values, and use any values to validate any other values as part of a custom validation.